# Edit,Delete changes present in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Question 1** 
I am completely new to GitLab, so just I thought is there any way that we can edit, delete update or make the decision to whether to keep that changes or discard it after merge request is generated.

**Question 2** 
Can we edit, delete in pull request means before creating a merge request.
Or is there another way to perform this through ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got what you are asking. But just guessing.

Yes you can edit/update/delete changes made in your merge requests. Just checkout to your branch `git checkout <your_branch>`, run an interactive rebase (see `git rebase -i`) and force push your branch again `git push origin <your_branch> --force`.

This works also on master if your requests are merged and you have push rights to master. But you should be very careful with force pushing to master.

Comment: can you share some screenshots or video to see it in, live preview type

Comment: Just search for it on youtube. You will get results like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tukOm3Afd8s).

Comment: does GitLab UI desktop has this rebase feature or it's just available in the command

Comment: Rebasing is not a GitLab feature. It is a git feature. So it could be supported from every git UI client. I'm just using git's CLI so cannot tell you.

Comment: ok will cross-check this git rebase and if its what I wanted then will mark it as answer